# Calculating sum of variables

Tags: python, list, variables, sum

I want to find out what the total score is that you give each sport in my coding.

Just to note that I have previously asked them to enter a state in a different function.

```
STATES = ["California", "New Mexico", "Ohio", "Maryland"]   
SPORTS = ["Football", "Baseball", "Basketball"]

def results(any_state):   
 SCORE = []   
 STATES.remove("{}" .format(any_state.title()))  
 for i in range(len(STATES)):  
  for j in range(len(SPORTS)):   
   scores = int(raw_input("What do you score {} in {}?".format(SPORTS[j], STATES[i])))
   SCORE.append(STATES[i])  
   SCORE.append(scores)   
   return(SCORE)
```

If California was entered I would like it to end up printing.

What do you score Football in New Mexico?

What do you score Football in Ohio?

What do you score Football in Maryland?

You scored Football a total of ____.

What do you score Baseball in New Mexico?

What do you score Baseball in Ohio?

What do you score Baseball in Maryland?

You scored Baseball a total of ____.

What do you score Basketball in New Mexico?

What do you score Basketball in Ohio?

What do you score Basketball in Maryland?

You scored Basketball a total of ____.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sum(scores)
```

As long as `scores` is a list (or iterable)

But the way you create and use `SCORES` is very strange. It would be a lot easier to create a dict:

```
def results(any_state):   
 SCORE = {}
 for i in range(len(STATES)):  
   for j in range(len(SPORTS)):   
     scores = int(raw_input("What do you score {} in {}?".format(SPORTS[j], STATES[i])))
     SCORE[STATES[i]) = scores
```

return(SCORE)

You can then use:

```
sum(SCORE.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
STATES = ["California", "New Mexico", "Ohio", "Maryland"]
SPORTS = ["Football", "Baseball", "Basketball"]

def results(state):
    for i in SPORTS:  # iterate for sports so that you can maintain your order of question by sports
        temp_scores = []   # construct a temporary list to create score
        for j in STATES:  #  iterate over states
            if j.lower() != state.lower():  # execute code only if iterated state is not same as state passed as function argument (case-insensitive match if you use .lower())
                scores = int(raw_input("What do you score {} in {}?".format(i, j)))
                temp_scores.append(scores)   # append scores
        print("You scored {} a total of {}".format(i, sum(temp_scores)))   # print score

results(STATES[0])  # call function with state
```

Comment: is it possible to add the state in the last print statement also. So i want to say "Your state () scored a total of () in ()"

Comment: yes, you need to do string formatting and keep track on response as per your use